# Python: line split and join

Tags: python, join, split

I have a file with contents in following format:

`a1 b1 c1 d1|e1|f1|path/file_name/n`

`a2 b2 c2 d2|e2|f2|path/file_name/n`

In the above string, file names can have space and thus the above one can change to:

`a b c d|e|f|path/file name.txt`

I need to iterate through each line in a file to search the records containing file name. and while searching, I need to match with certain contents in a given line for e.g. if a > x and e = 'test' etc.. as part of the search.

To begin, I tried, below:

```
for line in data_file:
    f_a f_b f_c f_d = line.split(' ')
```

Above works fine if file name doesn't have spaces and if it has space, then error out as 'too many values to unpack'.(expected 4)
If I use,

```
f_a f_b f_c f_d = line.rsplit(' ', 3)
```

then it does not store the file with name after 1st space.

Can anyone please suggest solution to this problem.

Comment: just use line.split('|')... it will work

Comment: You can't line.split(' ') without first replacing the space within the filename.  Otherwise it will split the filename apart.  I would advise just not allowing spaces in file names, in general, and not bother trying to worry about replacing the space between the file name, especially since you are using spaces as a delimiter.  Also, I would suggest delimiting each separate element with a similar character, as in the CSV standard where each new element on a line is separated with a comma. Are you already using a uniform delimiter because I can't really tell?

Comment: you have to split twice, first with `|`, then with space.

Answer (score 1):

If it is true that in all rows the filename is the string after the last `'|'`, then try splitting with that first.

Using `a b c d|e|f|path/file name.txt` as the example, first do

```
f_list, f_e, f_f, filename = line.split('|')
```

This gets you the path + filename in `filename` whether it has a space or not. Then you can split `f_list` further the way you are currently doing:

```
f_a, f_b, f_c, f_d = f_list.split(' ')
```